# does conversion of varchar(MAX) columns to int result in data loss

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 'varchar(MAX)' datatype column in SQL server table which I want to alter into 'int' datatype. Does it results in loss of data.

Comment: Obviously yes.  The `varchar()` column may not even contain digits, much less digits in the range of an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will results in loss of data depends on existing values in that column. You can test it as shown below -

```
 declare @tmp_tbl table (col_1 varchar(max))

 insert into @tmp_tbl (col_1)
 select '12345'
 union all
 select '1098.98'
 union all
 select 'abcde'
 union all
 select '2147483647'
 union all
 select '2147483648'

 select try_convert(int, col_1)
 from @tmp_tbl
```

`Try_Convert` function will return Null when value is not convertible to Int.

Comment: `try_convert` was introduced in 2012. running this script on 2008 will raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql), we can find that the largest bigint value is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, i.e. a number with a width of 19 characters.  On the other hand, `varchar(max)` can be substantially wider than 19 characters.  So if your text data has numbers larger than this max int value, casting would overflow an int column.